# Vue Js add event listener trigger immediately

Tags: vue.js

i am using onclick function to add an event listenner to parent class on click and it trigger immediately

```
<button v-on:click="greet">Try it</button>
```

this is the function

```
greet: function(e){
 document.getElementById("st-container").addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.bodyClickFn();
      }.bind(this));
}
```

"st-container" is the parent class that cover the button

the function `this.bodyClickFn();`is fire immediately

```
<div class="st-container">
 .
 .
<button v-on:click="greet">Try it</button>
 .
 .
</div>
```

this is the entire vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="st-container" class="st-container">
            <!--    
                example menus  st-effect-11 st-menu-open
                these menus will be on top of the push wrapper
            -->

            <nav class="st-menu st-effect-11" id="menu-11">
                <h2 class="icon icon-lab">Sidebar</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <router-link class="link" :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <router-link class="link" :to="{ name: 'hello' }">Hello World</router-link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <router-link class="link" :to="{ name: 'hello' }">Hello World</router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/main/hello">Hello World</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- content push wrapper -->
            <div class="st-pusher" style="height: 90vh">
                <!--    
                    example menus 
                    these menus will be under the push wrapper
                -->

                <div class="st-content">
                    <!-- this is the wrapper for the content -->
                    <div class="st-content-inner">
                        <!-- extra div for emulating position:fixed of the menu -->
                        <!-- Top Navigation -->

                        <header class="codrops-header">
                            <h1>Sidebar Transitions <span>Transition effects for off-canvas views</span></h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="main clearfix">
                            <div id="st-trigger-effects" class="column">
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-1">Slide in on top</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-2">Reveal</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-3">Push</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-4">Slide along</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-5">Reverse slide out</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-6">Rotate pusher</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-7">3D rotate in</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-8">3D rotate out</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-9">Scale down pusher</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-10">Scale Up</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-11">Scale &amp; rotate pusher</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-12">Open door</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-13">Fall down</button>
                                <button data-effect="st-effect-14">Delayed 3D Rotate</button>

                            </div>
                            <router-view></router-view>
                            <button v-on:click="greet">Try it</button>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <h1>food</h1>
                            <div class="column">
                                <p>Sidebar menus or off-canvas navigations can be revealed in many creative ways.</p>
                                <p>Here is some inspiration for showing them in style using CSS transitions.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                <p>If you enjoyed this demo you might also like:</p>
                                <p><a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/HeaderEffects/">On Scroll Header Effects</a></p>
                                <p><a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/">A Collection of Page Transitions</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /main -->
                    </div><!-- /st-content-inner -->
                </div><!-- /st-content -->
            </div><!-- /st-pusher -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    greet: function(e) {
      document
        .getElementById("st-container")
        .setAttribute("class", "st-container st-effect-11 st-menu-open");

      document.getElementById("st-container").addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.bodyClickFn();
      }.bind(this));
    },
    resetMenu: function() {
      document.getElementById("st-container");
    },
    bodyClickFn: function() {
      console.log("asdasda");
      this.resetMenu();

      document
        .getElementById("st-container")
        .removeEventListener("click", this.bodyClickFn);
      document
      .getElementById("st-container")
      .addEventListener("click", this.bodyClickFn);
    }
  }
};
</script>





<style lang="css" scoped>
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.st-container,
.st-pusher,
.st-content {
  height: 100%;
}

.st-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #f3efe0;
}

.st-content,
.st-content-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.st-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.st-pusher {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.st-pusher::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
}

.st-menu-open .st-pusher::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.st-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #48a770;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.st-menu::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.st-menu-open .st-menu::after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
}

/* content style */

.st-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.st-menu h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.st-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.2em;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #f3efe0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.st-menu ul li:first-child a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.st-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
}

.st-effect-11.st-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.st-effect-11 .st-pusher {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.st-effect-11.st-menu-open .st-pusher {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, -600px) rotateY(-20deg);
  transform: translate3d(100px, 0, -600px) rotateY(-20deg);
}

.st-effect-11.st-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-11.st-menu-open .st-effect-11.st-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-11.st-menu::after {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening? I don't get it from your question. You meant to say that the function this.bodyClickFn is running instantly when you click the button? Why would you add an event listener to the upper class on click of the inner button? Makes no sense.

Comment: Well you set a Event Listener in your click so it fires, but why do you even do such a weird mess, what is your goal?

Comment: it is a webpage that move the page into background , and then show the sidebar . whenever i click on the screen , it suppose to fall back to page ...

Comment: this is the image of what i the screen look like , which the event listener add to parent should be trigger when i click on page to turn back to normal page https://imgur.com/a/OCqugHe

Comment: This is a poor use of Vue; you're losing most of the advantages of the framework doing things this way. Don't manipulate the DOM directly; this manually-bound event listener would get wiped out when the component re-renders.  Instead use Vue's @click bindings for events, and $refs instead of `document.getElementById` (which makes the component non-reusable).  Let the framework do the work for you instead of you working around the framework.

Comment: @DanielBeck oke thanks for the guidance, just started to use it to replace laravel blade, it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're greatly misusing vue. Firstly, you generally shouldn't need to use `document.get` because you should be using `this.$refs`. Secondly you can toggle classes using dynamic classes `:class`

So you can simplify your lines to:

```
<div @click="bodyClickFn" id="st-container" class="st-container" :class="{'st-effect-11': clickable, 'st-menu-open': clickable}" ref="container">
```

```
<button v-on:click.stop="greet">Try it</button>
```

note the `.stop` after `click`, this is basically calling `stopPropagation`

```
  data()
  {
    return {
      clickable: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    greet: function(e) {
      this.clickable = true
    },
    resetMenu: function() {
      this.clickable = false
    },
    bodyClickFn: function() {
      if (!this.clickable)
      {
        return
      }
      this.resetMenu();
    }
  }
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vwmvxm193

I'd recommend you to actually watch some youtube tutorials before using this any further. Because there's no point in using Vue if you have no intention of actually making use of its functionalities.

Comment: yea i solved it yesterday with a similar ways , but still using DOM ...  ``` closeSidebar: function(e) {
      if (this.changes != false) {
        document
          .getElementById("st-container")
          .classList.remove("st-menu-open");
        this.changes = false;
      }
    },
    openSidebar: function(e) {
      document.getElementById("st-container").classList.add("st-menu-open");
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.changes = true;
      }, 500);
    } ```  it working , that the great things : > thanks for your answer

Comment: @CheongHaoYoong then you're still greatly misusing Vue. There's no point in using Vue if you're still going to do manual DOM manipulations.